# How to update OpenGrok indices

Tags: opengrok

The OpenGrok wrapper script has an update option, but when I run it without any options (as echoed in the usage), I get

> Loading the default instance configuration ...
>
> FATAL ERROR: OpenGrok Source Path /var/opengrok/src doesn't exist - Aborting!

I have also tried specifying the SRC_ROOT, but continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the right answer, but I have been able to update by re-running the index job itself. It doesn't take as long as the initial indexing.

Answer (score 1):

from https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok

E.g. if opengrok data directory is /tank/opengrok and source root is
in /tank/source then to get more verbosity run the indexer as:

> $ OPENGROK_VERBOSE=true OPENGROK_INSTANCE_BASE=/tank/opengrok \
>          ./OpenGrok index /tank/source

Answer (score 0):

`SRC_ROOT` is a variable in the OpenGrok wrapper (normally in `/usr/opengrok/bin/OpenGrok`), this variable is to say OpenGrok where you have your src code to be indexed. So you need to edit it:

```
SRC_ROOT="your/src/path"
```

Also, after that maybe you'll se an error for the Data location... and you have to set also the variable `DATA_ROOT` (index location)

```
DATA_ROOT="you/data"
```